# Add a prefix string to each of the command line parameters

Tags: linux, bash

I have a requirement, Where I am storing all the command line parameters in a string, (Can't store it in an array, because of other restrictions).

My question is, I want to prefix all the command line parameters stored in the string "services".

```
    services=$( echo $* | tr -d '/' )
    ---------------------------
    ??
    ---------------------------
    >./script.bash web studio
```

should generate the following output.

```
test-web test-studio
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use sed command, this should be enough:

```
params=$(echo " $services" | sed "s/\ / $prefix/g")
```

then just 'echo' params var

Comment: It worked. Can you make it more generic by passing prefix as a variable? I can't make it right, I tried with various escape sequences.

Comment: I found the solution, replace single quote with double quote would solve this problem. Your solution was the main factor though.

Answer (score 0):

In bash, you can do:

```
echo "test-"{web,studio}
test-web test-studio
```

If a=web;b=studio:

```
echo "test-"{$a,$b}
test-web test-studio
```